# How to retrieve a list of discord users in a channel

Tags: c#, discord

I'm trying to write something in C#, a simple console app that will connect to Discord, retrieve a list of all users in a channel (all currently online would suffice, but everyone who has channel access would be even better.) The app does not need to maintain a connection, just jump in, grab the list of user names and jump out.

I've experimented with DiscordSharp, but it doesn't seem to quite be working out. I think I am getting a client connection but I can't seem to find any channels via GetChannelByName or GetChannelByID. I am not set on using DiscordSharp as the only solution, though I do like the library so far.

Comment: Please share your code that you tried and then anyone can be more helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 5):

A "server" in discord is called a [Guild](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/guild).  Per the documentation a `Guild` can have a list of [Channel](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel) objects.  In the `Channel` object there is a property called `recipients` which should give you all users of that channel.

I wouldn't recommend using DiscordSharp because [according to their GitHub](https://github.com/suicvne/DiscordSharp) it is a dead project.  They recommend using [DSharpPlus](https://github.com/DSharpPlus/DSharpPlus) or [Discord.NET](https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.Net).

I just checked [the documentation](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/) for Discord.NET and found a few methods you could use:

[`GetGuildAsync(UInt64, RequestOptions)`](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.Rest.DiscordRestClient.html#Discord_Rest_DiscordRestClient_GetGuildAsync_System_UInt64_Discord_RequestOptions_): This will get you the [RestGuild](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.Rest.RestGuild.html) (server) based on the server ID.

[`GetChannelAsync(UInt64, RequestOptions)`](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.Rest.DiscordRestClient.html#Discord_Rest_DiscordRestClient_GetChannelAsync_System_UInt64_Discord_RequestOptions_): This will get you the [RestChannel](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.Rest.RestChannel.html) based on the channel ID.

Using either one of these will eventually get you a `RestChannel` object that will contain a [`GetUsersAsync(CacheMode, RequestOptions)`](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.Rest.RestChannel.html#Discord_Rest_RestChannel_Discord_IChannel_GetUsersAsync_Discord_CacheMode_Discord_RequestOptions_) method that will allow you to get the collection of [`IUSer`](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.IUser.html)

Answer (score 0):

In a command module you can do this:

```cs
public class AllUsers : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
    public async Task Traitement()
    {
        var users = Context.Guild.Users; 
        //you can loop here on users and do the traitement
    }
}
```